# Drawing from an ArrayList drawing same image repeatedly (Slick2D)

Tags: java, slick

This is the game I'm working on.
[image: What my problem looks like]

I isolated the problem into this class.

```
public class Runa extends BasicGame {
int startTime, tracker;
public ArrayList<Circle> circ = new ArrayList<Circle>();
public int[] a = new int[]{
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 32, 36, 40, 45, 46, 55, 56, 57, 58, 63, 65, 68, 70, 72, 74, 79, 80, 81, 82, 86, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 
        100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 117, 120, 122, 126, 128, 129, 130, 131, 133, 138, 139, 140, 142, 149, 151, 155, 156, 
        158, 164, 166, 172, 174, 180, 182, 184, 188, 189};
public ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public Runa(String title) {
    super(title);
}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer c) throws SlickException {
    startTime = 0;
    tracker = 0;
    //this just transfers the hard coded values into an arraylist
    for(int i = 0; i<a.length;i++){
        aList.add(a[i]);
    }
}
@Override
public void update(GameContainer c, int d) throws SlickException {
    //this calculates the rhythm of the game
    startTime+=d;
    if(startTime>((60/(calcBPM(195.8,89)))*1000)){
        startTime=0;
        tracker++;
    }

    //this adds a new circle every time the current beat (tracker) reaches a beat on the aList
    if(aList.indexOf(tracker)>0)
        circ.add(new Circle(50,50,50));
    //this should just move one circle at a time, meaning I thought that only one circle would be added above, and move it down 4 px
    for(Circle circle: circ)
        circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY()+4);
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer c, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    //draws each circle in the arraylist
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    for(Circle circle: circ)
        g.draw(circle);
}
//calculates the bpm
public double calcBPM(double d, int numSecs){
    return d*60/numSecs;
}
public static void main(String[]args) throws SlickException{
    new AppGameContainer(new Runa("Test"),680, 480, false).start();
}
```

}

Why is it doing that weird stretch thing? Is that because I'm using an arraylist?

Comment: Because the old version of the circle is still on the screen when you draw a new one...

Answer (score 1):

The stretching is occurring because each circle that you add is getting moved down four pixels every time. For example:

Take this array:

`{ }`

> It will hold the Y coordinate of every circle.
>
> Your beat tracker reaches a beat on he lost and adds a circle. Let's put that circle at 50 y. The array now looks like this:

`{50}`

> After adding the circle, your code moves every circle in the array up four pixels, leaving our array looking like this:

`{54}`

> Now when you call your draw function, you have a circle at y = 54.

Next update cycle:

> Your beat tracker finds another beat and adds a circle to the list, again at 50 y. The array now looks like this:

`{54, 50}`

> Again your code moves every circle up 4 pixels, making your array look like this:

`{58, 54}`

> Now when you call your draw function, you get a circle at y = 54, and another at y = 58.

This is the stacking pattern you see.

Do you understand why that stacking pattern happens now?

Answer (score 0):

Though I've got no experience in programming with slick, I've experienced a very similar problem when drawing in the paint method of a panel

The solution was to call the super.paintComponent(g);
 method in each draw cycle

So it should look like this

`public void paint(Graphics g){
       super.paintComponent(g);
       // draw stuff here 
}`

I hope that helped at least a bit